# Using subplot-command to change an already existing subplot with lines in it to plot more lines

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a problem using the `subplot`-command:
When I create a figure for example like this

```
x = linspace(0,100);
y1 = x.^2;
y2 = x.^3;
figure;
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x,y1)
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(x,y2)
```

and then realise, that I forgot to Label the axis of the first subplot, I can just do

```
subplot(2,1,1)
xlabel('time in s')
```

and it works fine.
Now when I save this figure and open it again and I want to change something on the first subplot, it doesn't work like this. As soon as I do `subplot(2,1,1)` the lines in that subplot will be deleted. Sure I could use `get`- or `findobj`-commands to get the axis handles of that subplot and then change stuff about it, but that seems very elaborate.
So my question is: Is there a way to work around the behaviour that I described above and why does it even behave different when I just ploted it compared to when I reopen it from a file?

EDIT: Notice that I'm using Matlab R2010b if that matters

Comment: hmmmm. what's wrong with getting the handle using `findobj`; it's only a line...

Comment: nah, it's not only a line. Afterwards, I have to use that handle in every command and I have to use `set(handle,'XLabelString','String')` (or whatever) instead of just `xlabel('String')` which is much more Elaborate when you do it everytime. This question is not about solving a specific problem for a specific plot, it's more about how to do stuff as convenient as possible and generally understanding why this behaviour occurs.

Comment: No you don't have to use the handle every time, just use the handle in the subplot command to make it the current axes: `subplot(axHandle)` and then any `xlabel` or command acting on an `axes` object will use the current axes, which is the one you just activated.

Comment: @Hoki You are right, that works. Do you by Chance also know, why thise behaviour occurs on saved figures?

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer not using the `findobj` function I think this option also works by using the `subplot` to get the handle on your figure.

```
uiopen('filename.fig');
  for i=1:numberOfSubplot
    h(i)= subplot(x,y,i); %//fill in x y as your subplot structure
    xlabel(h(i),'new x-label')
  end
```

EDIT - alternative method:

```
h=hgload('filename.fig'); 
haxis=get(h,'children'); 
xlabel(haxis(1),'label 1') 
xlabel(haxis(2),'label 2')
```

tested on 2010b working fine here.

[image: result]

Comment: Doesn't work, also deletes everyhing that was plotted in the subplots before. Don't know, if you didn't test it before, or it might be a matter of different matlab Versions. Besides I would really be interested in Information to why the figures behave differently after being reopened from a file. EDIT: nevertheless, I didn't know you could use `xlabel` like that. This helps me a bit.

Comment: weird, works fine here. Maybe a version issue. Do you want to try the alternative version? As for why this behaviour is, I do not have enough knowledge to give you the full answer, so I think I will wait for someone else to explain.